# IMacros with proxy script

Tags: javascript, loops, firefox, proxy, imacros

**Is there any way where we can change proxy in iMacros Firefox extension together with checking if the proxy is running or not??**

Below is the code to change proxy, but cant figure out a way to check whether the proxy is running or not?

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !DATASOURCE proxies.csv

SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2

SET !LOOP 1

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

SET !TIMEOUT 60

CLEAR

'proxy module

URL GOTO=about:config

URL GOTO=javascript:varprefb=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);varstr=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);str.data="{{!COL1}}";prefb.setComplexValue("network.proxy.http",Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString,str);

URL GOTO=about:config

URL GOTO=javascript:gPrefBranch.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port",{{!COL2}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki.imacros.net/PROXY

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !DATASOURCE proxies.csv

SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

SET !TIMEOUT 60

CLEAR

PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL2}})
```

You can try it your way or this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *JavaScript* code for changing proxy address and port.

```
var ProxyIP = '121.43.146.196';
var ProxyPort = '1080';
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.type", 1);
Services.prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.http", ProxyIP);
Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port", ProxyPort);
```